# Reference problems when using custom controls within Exrin

Tags: xamarin.forms, exrin

Using the base Exrin template, I am unable to use custom controls.

As it stands now, the Droid/iOS projects reference the App/Bootstrapper project, so that seems like the correct place to put them, but when creating a new page or `BaseView`, I am not able to access the custom control's namespace because the View project does not reference the App/Bootstrapper project.

The Tesla sample app does not have this problem in its current implementation since there is no separation of the App/Bootstrapper and the View projects.

(1) Should a reference to the App/Bootstrapper be placed in the View project or (2) should a reference to the View project be placed in the Android/iOS/etc projects? Or is there a better solution than either of these two?

Edit: 
(1) does not work because a reference to the App project from the View would create a circular dependency.

(2) should work (I think), but I'm having trouble getting the Application.Droid project to access the Application.View project namespace because when I add `using Application.View;`, the namespace isn't found in the Application namespace. Visual Studio attempts to fill in other Application namespaces (.Container, .Logic, .Droid, .Proxy) when I type in `using Application.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native project can have a reference to the View. It already does in a way, because it references the App library, which then references the View. Hence you aren't really adding any further dependencies by doing this, just allowing access further up the chain.

If you are having trouble the namespace, I suggest you start out with

```
global::Application.
```

That way it starts from the top, if its getting mixed up with project namespaces.

Comment: This isn't working for me. I created an Application.CustomControls namespace. The Application.Droid project can get to this just fine. The .View project does not even when using `global::Application.CustomControls`. I tried putting the CustomControls namespace in the .View project and using `global::Application.View.CustomControls` in the .Droid project for the renderer, but it still didn't work. Thoughts?

Comment: Where is this Application.CustomControls namespace? It it in the View project or somewhere else?

Comment: It's in the bootstrapper project. The .View project can't access the bootstrapper project and the .Droid project can't access the .View project. If it's in the bootstrapper, the .View needs access to it to add to the view files. If it's in the .View project, I can add it to my view files, but the .Droid project can't access it to reference the PCL class in the Droid renderer.

Comment: A CustomControl should be in the View project, and a custom renderer for it, in the native Droid project. It shouldnt be with the bootstrapper. If you need to inject something into the IoC container, then you can add it to the bootstrapper in the native Droid project (not the App project).

Comment: If I put it in the .View project, the renderer in the .Droid project can't reference the .View PCL class even when attempting to reference it using `global::Application.View`

Comment: What is your namespace in the View project. Does it start with Application? Are you able to screenshot your project and place it in your question, so I can get a better idea of everything? If your Droid project, references your View project, and the complete namespace of the Custom control is Application.View.CustomControl.ControlName, then adding global:: to the front of that will reference it. I think I might not be understanding something here.

Comment: For whatever reason this is working now. Both the `using` statement and the `global::` statement.